# OnMouseDown() doesn't work when object's collider is colliding with another collider on the mouse position

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I think the title speaks for itself. I'm using 2D Colliders, and they're on the same Z position. OnMouseDown() doesn't get triggered if you're clicking another object's collider as well. This is pretty annoying. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for me it gets triggered always on one of the objects, but I cannot choose which one.

As a workaround you can add a child gameObject with 3D collider (for example `Box Collider`). The child is needed because both 2D and 3D colliders cannot be attached to same gameObject. Make the 3D collider expand towards camera a little bit. In that case the child gameObjects OnMouseDown() is always called.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I could very well do that, but are you sure this is the best way?

Comment: No idea if that is the best way, but I don't know any better. In away, it sounds odd that the scene has two colliders inside each other all the time. Could it be better to just change the size of the other one?

Comment: I guess I could do it with a 3D Collider; it's not a big deal. I can't change the size of the other one, it's important. I'm using the collider (The one that handles the clicks) to set a hit area for the player to attack. If the player clicks on a Enemy's collider, then (and only then) OnMouseDown() doesn't get triggered. It surprises me that I didn't find any topics on this site regarding this. Maybe I'm missing something. Then again, I'm aware that this can be done in other ways, but why not this way?